# how to pass one input item value to another input item?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having two input item

```
            <td> <input type="number" id="primaryincome2"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
           value="<?php echo (!isset($student2['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>"
         disabled> </td>

         <td> <input type="text" > </td>
```

based on first item the value will be posted in second item. need suggestion.

Comment: you could use javascript to simply copy the value as it changes. The second input will need a name in any case. _But_: What's the problem you wanna solve with that? Sounds like an XY Problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input type="number" id="primaryincome2"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
       value="<?php echo (!isset($student2['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>"
     > </td>
     <td> <input type="text" id="eprimaryincome2"> </td>

     <script>
     $("#primaryincome2").on("keyup click",function(){
        $("#eprimaryincome2").val($(this).val());
     })
     </script>
```

try this, You can use both in mouse and keyboard event.

Answer (score -1):

If you are ready to use jquery ,  you can use this code,

```
<td> <input onkeyup="$('#eprimaryincome2').val(this.value)" type="number" id="primaryincome2"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
           value="<?php echo (!isset($student2['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>"
         disabled> </td>

         <td> <input type="text" id="eprimaryincome2" > </td>
```

Comment: onkeyup will not trigger on a mouse-click, will it?

Comment: @Jeff You can use onclick event

Comment: I'm not the OP. Just wanted to point out that your solution will only work partially.

Comment: onclick - mouse-click working onkeyup- keyboard working. but i want both functionality.

Comment: @vana You need to write both

Comment: finally i am using both event onkeyup and onclick.